# how to tell if two sequences differ by a permutation?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, graph, permutation, combinatorics

Given any two sequences of n real numbers, say (a1,a2,...,an) and (b1,b2,...,bn), how to tell if one sequence (which can also be viewed as a vector) is a permutation of the other?

I plan to develop an algorithm and run it on Matlab to do this job. I can only think of an algorithm that costs n! times: just try all the permutations in n.

Is there a faster algorithm?

Comment: Sort, compare pairwise.

Comment: Sort and then compare - `O(n log n)` (or) place all of `a`s in a map with frequency as value and then look for the same frequency in `b` - `O(n)` but `O(n)` space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why n! ? if for every ai you search a match in bi you will get O(n^2).
Anyway it is more efficient to use sort with O(nlogn) complexity.

```
A=[3,1,2,7];
B=[2,3,1,7];
isPermutated=isequal(sort(A),sort(B))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just sort both sequences and compare sorted results.

*In some situations you might find useful create sets/map/dictionary (with counters if multiple elements are possible) from both sequences and check every element presence in another set.*